# Airplay plus Bluetooth Speaker

Tags: audio, bluetooth, shairplay, audio-playback

I would like to develop a Raspberry PI "music receiver" that would play Airplay audio by default, but if a Bluetooth audio source connected to it - it would use that as the audio source instead of Airplay.

Airplay requires users to be on the same WIFI network, but I would like to allow visitors with Bluetooth phones to be able to send music to my speakers. I am hoping for something automated. It means that I need to detect a Bluetooth audio connection and send a command to switch the audio source for the Airplay receiver software the Bluetooth receiver software. When the Bluetooth connection goes away - revert to the Airplay source.

I am planning on using a USB sound DAC to connect audio out to an amplifier.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow these two tutorials here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/44918/raspberry-pi-airplay-tutorial

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=68779

Comment: Uh-oh: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Answer (score 0):

The balena-sound enables you to add multi-room audio streaming via Bluetooth, Airplay, Spotify Connect and others to any old speakers or Hi-Fi using just a Raspberry Pi.

https://github.com/balenalabs/balena-sound